# height:100% glitchy in Android Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

For some reason, 100% height isn't working properly in Firefox on my Nexus 4. What's more frustrating is that if I open the address bar, then close it, the 100% IS working properly.

See #MainHeader (the first thing you see when you load the page) on http://brantbweb.com/tfs